# Impersonation by this user requires the DOMAIN\MTSUSER account to be configured as impersonation user

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am getting the below error frequently in the GUI when i try to access my custom application. and some time it preventing me to do anything in GUI. Could any one help me on this to resolve?

I am using Tridion 2011 SP1

**(80040302) Impersonation by this user requires the DOMAIN\MTSUSER account to be configured as impersonation user.
Unable to get a User.
Unable to Initialize TDSE object.RESID_4537TDSE
Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.GetImpersonationUserSettings(String)
Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String,String)
Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String,String,UserContext)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.SystemFacade.InitializeUserContext(UserContext,String,String)
UtilitiesTDS.GetUserContext
TDSE.Initialize
TDSE.User**

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "when i try to access my custom application"?

Answer (score 3):

I think the error is quite clear. It seems that your application is running under `DOMAIN\MTSUSER` and you are trying to impersonate (perform action as user that is logged in to Tridion GUI). To make it work you should either run your application under one of the impersonation users, `NETWORK SERVICE`, for example, or any other user you can find under `Impersonation Users` in Tridion MMC, otherwise just add `DOMAIN\MTSUSER` to impersonation users in MMC

Answer (score 3):

As the error states, you need to add the DOMAIN\MTSUSER account, to the impersonation user lists

You can find this option in the Tridion MMC Snap In (aka: **"Sdl Tridion Content Manager Configuration"**) under the impersonation users list.

[image: MMC Snap In]

However you should ask yourself what tasks are you doing with this user, and is it the correct account to do it?

Comment: Be very careful adding MTSUSer as an impersonation user,and only do so if there is a genuine business reason for doing so. I believe you introduce possible security vulnerabilities by doing so. You really should run your code as some other user as Puntero suggests.